# How to place two elements side by side in HTML

Tags: html, css, button, input

I want to place button and H3 side by side. but H3 is appearing under input

```html
<div id="input2">
  <input>
  <h3><button id="input">Add</button></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: just add `#input2 { display: flex; }`

Answer (score 0):

By using flexbox you can achieve it.

```css
#input2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="input2">
  <input> 
  <h3><button id="input">Add</button></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: @bilawalBhatti, have you changed "Accept answer" recently ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put *input* and *button* (without h3) inside a *div* block. Take a look at  in the following code:

I suggest you read this article about flex box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#input2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="t.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input2">
        <input>
        <button id="input">Add</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```