# Two Elements next to each other

Tags: html, css

I need to make **MAIN** and **NAV** elements next to each other.
Text "test" should be to the right of navbar in element **MAIN**
Here is my code with snippet:

```css
*, html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 87.5%;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.navbar__left {
    position: fixed;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #131313;
}

nav .title {
    height: 10%;
}

nav .title img {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}

nav .links {    
    margin: 50% 0 50% 0;
}

nav .links ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav .links ul li {
    margin: 25px 0;
}

nav .links ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

nav .copyright {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar__left">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="">LOGO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="uzitocne-odkazy.php">UŽITOČNÉ ODKAZY</a></li>
            <li><a href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright">
        <b>NIEKTO </b>© 2022 
    </div>
</nav>
<main>test</main>
```

Everytime I tried some solution, it didn't work. I also tried to Google it / find already solved problems like this but none of them didn't work. Can somebody help me please?
Thanks
furtake

Comment: put your `<nav>` and `<main>` inside a flex container ***display:flex**;*, make sure its direction is set to row ***flex-direction:row*** *(which is by default)* you wouldn't need `position: fixed;` on the nav then

Comment: @Zohini I tried it but it doesn't work for some reason :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place two elements side by side in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954267/how-to-place-two-elements-side-by-side-in-html)

Comment: Are you sure ? https://jsfiddle.net/sp9L18jy/

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the `nav` sits directly on top of the main element. If you remove `background-color: #fff` on line 26, you will see that "test" is on the top left, behind the `nav`. If you assign `margin-left: 12.5%` (which is the width of your `nav` element) to the `main` that should shift the main element to the right of the `nav` into view, like this:

```
main {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}
```

And also, as a suggestion, in HTML documents, try to refrain from using the copyright symbol itself. I would recommend using the escaped version or `&copy;` in your HTML. So `<b>NIEKTO </b>&copy; 2022`. Produces the same effect.